# How do I have a chip in between of a normal text inside of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-chips

Hi I do want to have this design in my App (screenshot taken from a web app):

[image: Test <PILL> Test]

I do know about the [Material Components for Chips](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) already. But how can I dynamicly at runtime either split up multiple TextViews with a Chip in between or have the Chip inside of the TextView? Is this possible without for example a Webview?

The Text is not known at build time. It is a chat app. Means I would want to decide at runtime where and how often to place a chip in the text. The raw text would be this: `Test <a href=\"https://matrix.to/#/@DasNordlicht:matrix.ffslfl.net\">DasNordlicht</a>  Test` if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the Material Components Chip documentation:

> You can also directly use a standalone ChipDrawable in contexts that require a Drawable. For example, an auto-complete enabled text field can replace snippets of text with a ChipDrawable using a span to represent it as a semantic entity.

So to use a Chip within a TextView, you would create an [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan) that uses a ChipDrawable as its image and that can be included in the TextView's text.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about ImageSpan yet :) After 5 hours of digging it finally works. (Had some issues with themes and the passed context)

Comment: @MTRNord Great!

Comment: @MTRNord Had some issues with themes and the passed context -> please, update the code with this part :)

Comment: @anna_manzhula I actually can't I think (I will dig into my archive). This code was part of a project that I stopped working on. I don't even think I ever commited this into the source tree in the end. I will try to find the relevant code lines.